Update Interfaces in the Simulator (without SwiftUI)
I have this example:
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Line where the breakpoint will be placed
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    }
}

I want to add breakpoint, execute the app on the simulator, and when the execution is paused, I want to update the backgroundColor to blue and see the background on the simulator on blue color without reset the application.

I found the solution, when the execution is paused I executed the expression "e view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue", but the UI on the simulator does not updated. So I executed the expression on the main thread with "e DispatchQueue.main.async { self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue }" and works. UI was updated on the simulator.

Hey, glad you found a solution. Could you please post it as an answer and accept it to prevent the community bot from bumping it as unanswered? :)

@Thinkr I can not accept my own answer, how can I do this?

You can only accept your answer 2 days after the question has been asked, so you'll have to wait ~7h now. :)

Nice. Is good to know. Thanks for the tip.
